# Obtain all vectors from a Matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, vector

I'm facing a little problem and I'd like to get some help. 
The thing is I'm given this control matrix H.

```
      0000111111111
H =   0111000111222
      1012012012012
```

I'm asked to obtain all the words of this code. The theory of linear and block codes says that a word V is that word which **H*Vt=0 (zero)** where Vt is transposed V.

At the moment I do know there are 3^10 = 59049 possible words. That is the size of the matrix which is obtained by powering the body q *in this case q=3* of the matrix to the dimension which is columns-rows.

**My problem is** I dont know how to generate all the vectors (words) so H*Vt = 0. How could I do that on Java? All possible combinations using 13-n vectors with 0,1 and 2. I'd also like to know if there is possible to work with matrices in Java.

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
.... 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2] 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2]
....
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
...
[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
[1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Thank you so much!
**I'd like to implement it in a general way, I mean, not only for this matrix but for every matrix I could work with**

Comment: What is the underlying scalar field (R? C? Z/3Z?)

Comment: All operations are modulo q (in this case modulo 3)

Comment: It sounds like doing this by explicitly enumerating all vectors is silly and that there should be simpler ways to solve the problem with math.

Comment: Take a look at http://jblas.org/ its a Java linear algebra library that uses multi-threading.  Also, i'd recommend to solve this problem mathematically, and only then, translate that math algorithm to Java implementation.

Comment: Thank you for showing me jblas, I took a look but there seems to be nothing of my interest. I'm looking for combinations, which are usually trated as a pack with variations and permutations

Comment: http://jblas.org/javadoc/org/jblas/Solve.html you can use the Matrix operations so you dont have to implement them yourself, since you asked a way to work with matrices in java

Comment: Oh, that's great :D
I also found matrix.java http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/22library/Matrix.java.html
Thank you :D

Comment: JBlas does not support other fields than R and C from what I read, I doubt you will find what you need there.

Comment: I tested the code I commented on your answer, the one here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41510/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-given-characters and it work pretty well.

Comment: Are you sure it solves the same problem that you described? From your question, what you are looking for is not the set of all combinations. In particular, it does not account for H. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: JBlas has awful architecture. I recommend Apache Math.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: same thing, no Z/qZ support in Apache Math. The JBlas vs Apache Math argument is moot in this case.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is basically enumerating all the vectors in the kernel of H. To avoid reinventing the wheel, you'll want to find a Java linear algebra library that supports solving linear systems on finite fields (which rules out most of the popular Java linear algebra libraries).

I googled "Java linear algebra finite fields" and found this library: [JLinAlg](http://jlinalg.sourceforge.net/), which claims to support it.

All you have to do is find a basis for the kernel of H; after that, enumerating is simply a matter of listing all the linear combinations (coordinates) in this basis.

I would go for the [`org.jlinalg.LinSysSolver#solutionSpace()`](http://jlinalg.sourceforge.net/javadocs/index.html?org/jlinalg/LinSysSolver.html) method, which yields an [AffineSubSpace](http://jlinalg.sourceforge.net/javadocs/org/jlinalg/AffineLinearSubspace.html) that has `generatingSystem()` method which gives you the desired basis.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I'll take a look after finishing reading this one. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41510/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-given-characters Seems to be the one I'm needing